# Crash report for UWP app in Microsoft Store

Tags: c#, uwp, app-store, appx

I have uploaded my Appx bundle *(UWP app)* to the Microsoft store, it is certified and currently published and I tried launching it on my system. However, when I view the analytics report on Store I see there are 12 crashes. When I try to analysis the report the errors are not known.

I have two questions

1. How do I get the report for the crashes of my UWP app in the Microsoft App Store?
2. Do I have to use the App center to add crash report in my UWP code?

Answer (score 0):

Basic crash reporting is available automatically in the **Dev Center Dashboard**: Go to your app, open **Analytics** and select **Health**. You should see a list of crashes which can be filtered as well.

To get more detail crash analytics however, using App Center is advatageous. Integrating it is quite easy - just follow the instructions in [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/crashes/uwp). You will have to create your app in App Center and then add the App Secret to the `AppCenter.Start` call in your code.

Comment: Thanks. However I would like to know how can I get the crash reporting without using the App center. Is there a way I can get the detailed error list through the Microsoft App Store itself. Currently I am not able to identify the event on the page which is causing the app to crash. If I get that through the Microsoft app would be good. 

It seems like the App center is just a testing environment for the developers. But once my app is published how would I get the detailed error report in Microsoft.